# the difference between the following error

Tags: node.js, timeout, httprequest

when i use nodejs http library(Request) to request target website, i get some error:

```
    [{
        "response": {
            "code": "ECONNRESET",
            "errno": "ECONNRESET",
            "syscall": "read"
        }
    }, {
        "response": {
            "code": "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT",
            "connect": false
        }
    }, {
        "response": {
            "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "connect": true
        }
    }, {
        "response": {
            "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
            "connect": false
        }
    }]
```

i want to know the difference between these error.

Comment: The complete error list : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html IMHO, that's pretty self explanatory, google it for more.

Comment: @BorisCharpentier thanks, i sent this question to the author of this library,  waiting for response.